# Unrecognized function name in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008

When ever I try to execute the following I get

Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1
'dbname' is not a recognized built-in function name.

```
USE Personnel
GO
SELECT has_perms_by_name(dbname(), 'OBJECT', 'SELECT') as Have_Select,
* from sys.tables;
GO
```

I'm not sure if dbname() should be got replaced or if its a syntax error.

Comment: You probably want DB_NAME()

Comment: YOu got it I had no idea it was case sensitive

Comment: it's underscore sensitive ;)

Comment: Not case sensitive -- need that underscore :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the following which I've confirmed works:

```
USE Personnel
GO
SELECT has_perms_by_name(DB_NAME(), 'OBJECT', 'SELECT') as Have_Select, 
* from sys.tables;
GO
```

And as per a comment it's not case-sensitive, the problem was the missing underscore.

Comment: Your right I couldn't see the underscore was missing because of my type face.